# Get delta value corrected with different timestamps

Tags: java, sql, algorithm

**First, sorry for the title. I didn't know what is the best way to answer this. Any suggestion for a better title will be good**

I have a database with the following data:

```
ID                 UP            TIMESTAMP
---------- ---------- --------------------
2                   1  2016/01/01 00:00:00
3                   2  2016/01/01 01:00:00      
4                  16  2016/01/01 03:00:00
5                  32  2016/01/01 04:00:00
6                  42  2016/01/01 10:00:00
7                  66  2016/01/01 12:00:00
8                  78  2016/01/01 15:00:00
9                 100  2016/01/01 16:00:00
10                207  2016/01/01 20:00:00
```

The value in UP is always increasing. So, what I do to calculate the delta value is the following:

(value - lastvalue)/(timestamp - lasttimestamp)

This is calculared correctly, I can draw the information like this:

[image]

**THE PROBLEM** is that the timestamps are not separated in the same timeframe, so the graphic is somehow misleading because between values of the same length can have hours of different. So my question is, Is there any algorithm(in java or SQL) that could help me to fix the data so the gaps between each value are of the same timeframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the minimal time difference `(timestamp - lasttimestamp)` is `01:00:00`.

You can create a new temporary table like this:

```
ID                 UP            TIMESTAMP
---------- ---------- --------------------
2                   1  2016/01/01 00:00:00
3                   2  2016/01/01 01:00:00
4                   2  2016/01/01 02:00:00
5                  16  2016/01/01 03:00:00
6                  32  2016/01/01 04:00:00
7                  32  2016/01/01 05:00:00
8                  32  2016/01/01 06:00:00
9                  32  2016/01/01 07:00:00
10                 32  2016/01/01 08:00:00
11                 32  2016/01/01 09:00:00
12                 42  2016/01/01 10:00:00
13                 42  2016/01/01 11:00:00
14                 66  2016/01/01 12:00:00
15                 66  2016/01/01 13:00:00
16                 66  2016/01/01 14:00:00
17                 78  2016/01/01 15:00:00
18                100  2016/01/01 16:00:00
19                100  2016/01/01 17:00:00
20                100  2016/01/01 18:00:00
21                100  2016/01/01 19:00:00
22                207  2016/01/01 20:00:00
```

You can then plot the graph using this table. The time stamps will be separated with constant time frame.